# Why PWA can be installed only in dev mode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, progressive-web-apps, webpack-4

I'm trying to integrate PWA in my react project, when i run using `webpack-dev-server` i can see the PWA app that i can install in my computer, but when i build the project with `webpack` and try to run it, i can't do it anymore

**`webpack.config.js`**

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const { styles } = require("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils");
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');

const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "public");
const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

const envs = require('./config/envs').getEnv;
const plugins = require('./webpack-plugins');

module.exports = (env) => {
  console.log("OUTPUT: env", env)
  const config = envs(env.NODE_ENV);
  const mode = env.production ? 'production' : 'development';
  return {
    mode,
    entry: `${APP_DIR}/index.js`,
    output: {
      filename: "js/bundle.js",
      path: BUILD_DIR,
      publicPath: "/"
    },
    node: {
      net: "empty",
      tls: "empty",
      dns: "empty",
      fs: "empty"
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
          exclude: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css/
        },
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            "babel-loader",
            {
              loader: "eslint-loader",
              options: {
                failOnError: true,
                emitError: true,
                emitWarning: true
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "graphql-tag/loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg|pdf|ico)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "file-loader",
              options: {
                name: "[path][name]-[hash:8].[ext]"
              }
            }
          ],
          exclude: [
            /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
            /\.html$/,
            /\.json$/,
            /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
            /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css/
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
          use: ["raw-loader"]
        },
        {
          test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "style-loader",
              options: {
                singleton: true
              }
            },
            {
              loader: "postcss-loader",
              options: styles.getPostCssConfig({
                themeImporter: {
                  themePath: require.resolve("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark")
                },
                minify: true
              })
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
      watchContentBase: true,
      contentBase: "./public"
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".js"],
      alias: {
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        shared: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "shared"),
        config: path.resolve(__dirname, "config"),
        screens: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "screens"),
        package: path.resolve(__dirname, "package.json")
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new MomentLocalesPlugin({
        localesToKeep: ['es-us', 'fr', 'es'],
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        CONFIG: JSON.stringify(config),
      }),
      plugins.manifest,
      plugins.sw
    ]
  }
};
```

**the Scripts on `package.json`**

"build:local": "webpack --env.NODE_ENV=local --env.production --progress",

"start": "node server.js",

"dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --watch --host 0.0.0.0 --env.NODE_ENV=local --env.development --progress"

**Webpack packages used :**

"webpack": "4.19.1",
"webpack-cli": "^2.0.15",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3",
"webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.2.0"

***PS:** I tried both `--env.production` and `--env.development` in the build but neither worked*

**Any lead would be appreciated !**

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Comment: No it wasn't, i thought it wasn't necessary on local environment, it's fixed it only needed HTTPS to work, thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the app `HTTPS` fixed it, many thanks @Mathias